# double click visual element not in html to make textarea appear selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to enter text into a textarea. The problem is the `textarea` is only created and shows up in the html after clicking twice on a visual element in the browser. 
For this visual element `Dubbelklik om je tekst te typen`, I cannot find an element in the html that refers to it and perform a `double_click()`. There are only containers, that either are unclickable elements, or allow clicks, but don't perform an action.

Up until here it works and the visual cue to double click appears slightly below the center:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.hallmark.nl/kaarten/verjaardag-man/")
#wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='https://www.hallmark.nl:443/kaarten/verjaardag-man/grappig-m/make-that-the-cat-wise/happy-bursdeej-to-jou-3415094.aspx']"))).click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='https://www.hallmark.nl:443/kaarten/verjaardag-man/grappig-m/hallmark/een-jaguar-voor-je-verjaardag-3346861.aspx']"))).click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnShowSizepicker"))).click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Standaard']"))).click()
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'showDesktop')]//button[contains(text(),'Binnenkant')]"))).click()
```

But from then on I can't seem to find anything to make selenium click on the element. 
I have tried clicking the things I can locate in the html:

```
# elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'canvasAnchor')]").click()
```

This gives an `element not interactable` error. I have also tried using an offset for a findable element:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("canvas-container")
print(elem.location)
print(elem.size)
action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(elem, 0.5*elem.location.get('x'), (0.5*elem.location.get('y'))) #should click in the middle of this container
action.double_click()
action.perform()
```

But for different elements and values of x and y, I can only get it to do either nothing, or click on the contact sidebar (which highlights the word 'Neem').

If I click twice manually, a `textarea` appears in the html and I can execute `send_keys('hello world')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element where you have to click is actually `canvas`, so what you have to do is that  move cursor to the position where double click is needed and then click there.

I tried this over your code and worked for me:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="canvasWrapper active"]//*[@class="canvas-container"]')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(elem, 70, 60).double_click().perform()
```

Note:You may have to wait for the canvas element to load properly. I just tried from prompt.

You can read about this mouse action [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element_with_offset).

UPDATE:

I noticed that somehow the double click was behaving as single click for me, so changed to this.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="canvasWrapper active"]//*[@class="canvas-container"]')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(elem, 70, 60).click().perform()
time.sleep(1)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(elem, 70, 60).click().perform()
```

Comment: Hi Kamal, 3 questions: 1. how do you know which is the element to click, because there's also an inside canvas, upper canvas, lower canvas, and so on?
2. What did you base the x and y offset on?
3. With the code you provided, the textarea (triggered by clicking twice) does not appear. But it does seem if I click manually to make the textarea appear, I can 'unclick' the element by running your code.

Comment: 1. I was trying to click on the position where canvas has the text and is clickable. I was able to do the same using 'canvas-container' `div` element(as mentioned in answer), 'inside-canvas' `canvas` element and 'lower-canvas' `canvas` element because all of them are in same position.

Comment: 2. `move_to_element_with_offset` will take the top-left corner of the element as start point and move as per the offset given. I manually checked how much offset I need from top-left corner of `canvas` to reach the text. I think this could be the reason why it did not work for you. May be the offset will change based on screen size.
3. I think somehow the double click is behaving as single click in my case also, so I clicked once, then clicked again after 1s and it worked. I have updated the answer with that.

Comment: Perfect, it took some tries to get the x and y offset for my screen, but it works! Thank you for the explanation as well. So originally it didn't work for me because I could not find the right element and was clicking on non-clickable areas.